# How to implement a scrollspy with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollspy

I want to implement a *scrollspy* without the bootstrap.

I have checked a lot of code online, all of them are implemented by *jQuery*.

How to implement the *scrollspy* only with the power of React?

Answer (score 8):

### I've made a React *Wrapper* (used with [*Render-Props*](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)):

### ⚡ [Live Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/gOOjovv)

---

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef} = React;

/**
 *
 * @param {Object} scrollParent [DOM node of scrollable element]
 * @param {Array} _targetElements [Array of nodes to spy on]
 */
const spyScroll = (scrollParent, _targetElements) => {
  if (!scrollParent) return false;

  // create an Object with all children that has data-name attribute
  const targetElements =
    _targetElements ||
    [...scrollParent.children].reduce(
      (map, item) =>
        item.dataset.name ? { [item.dataset.name]: item, ...map } : map,
      {}
    );

  let bestMatch = {};

  for (const sectionName in targetElements) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(targetElements, sectionName)) {
      const domElm = targetElements[sectionName];
      const delta = Math.abs(scrollParent.scrollTop - domElm.offsetTop); // check distance from top, takig scroll into account

      if (!bestMatch.sectionName) 
        bestMatch = { sectionName, delta };

      // check which delet is closest to "0"
      if (delta < bestMatch.delta) {
        bestMatch = { sectionName, delta };
      }
    }
  }

  // update state with best-fit section
  return bestMatch.sectionName;
};




/**
 * Given a parent element ref, this render-props function returns
 * which of the parent's sections is currently scrolled into view
 * @param {Object} sectionsWrapperRef [Scrollable parent node React ref Object]
 */
const CurrentScrolledSection = ({ sectionsWrapperRef, children }) => {
  const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState();

  // adding the scroll event listener inside this component, and NOT the parent component, to prever re-rendering of the parent component when
  // the scroll listener is fired and the state is updated, which causes noticable lag.
  useEffect(() => {
    const wrapperElm = sectionsWrapperRef.current;
    if (wrapperElm) {
      wrapperElm.addEventListener('scroll', e => setCurrentSection(spyScroll(e.target)));
      setCurrentSection(spyScroll(wrapperElm));
    }

    // unbind
    return () => wrapperElm.removeEventListener('scroll', throttledOnScroll)
  }, []);

  return children({ currentSection });
};

function App(){
  const sectionsWrapperRef = useRef()
  return <CurrentScrolledSection sectionsWrapperRef={sectionsWrapperRef}>
    {({ currentSection }) => <div ref={sectionsWrapperRef}>
    <section 
      data-name="section-a" 
      className={currentSection === "section-a" ? 'active' : ''}
    >Section A</section>
    <section 
      data-name="section-b" 
      className={currentSection === "section-b" ? 'active' : ''}
    >Section B</section>
    <section 
      data-name="section-c" 
      className={currentSection === "section-c" ? 'active' : ''}
    >Section C</section>
    </div>
  }
  </CurrentScrolledSection>
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
html, body, #root{ height: 95%; overflow:hidden; }

#root > div{ 
  padding-bottom:20em; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow:auto; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section{ 
  height: 50vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

section.active{ background:lightyellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

It's not perfect because scroll direction does matter, since it implies on the intentions of the user.

Comment: could you help me adapt that to a top bar menu? I would need to change only the css of the Aside?

Answer (score 3):

## Live running Demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-wing-ue2ks

## Steps

### 1. Add the dependency

#### using npm

```
npm i react-scrollspy
```

#### or using yarn

```
yarn add react-scrollspy
```

### 2. Create your HTML sections

```
<section id="section-1">
    <!-- Content goes here -->
</section>
<section id="section-2">
    <!-- Content goes here -->
</section>

<!-- .... -->

<section id="section-n">
    <!-- Content goes here -->
</section>
```

### 3. Add those section's ID to Scrollspy `items`

```
<Scrollspy items={ ['section-1', 'section-2', ..., 'section-n'] } />
```

### 4. Add some styles

Check this documentation https://makotot.github.io/react-scrollspy/#section-3

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`react-ui-scrollspy`](https://github.com/pettiboy/react-ui-scrollspy#react-ui-scrollspy) it is very easy to use.

*Full disclosure: I maintain this package.*

1. In your navigation component

```
<div>
  <p data-to-scrollspy-id="first">Section 1</p>
  <p data-to-scrollspy-id="second">Section 2</p>
</div>
```

2. Wrap the elements you want to spy on in the `<ScrollSpy>` component.

```
import ScrollSpy from "react-ui-scrollspy";

<ScrollSpy>
  <div id="first">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut dolores
    veritatis doloremque fugit. Soluta aperiam atque inventore deleniti,
    voluptatibus non fuga eos magni natus vel, rerum excepturi expedita.
    Tempore, vero!
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut dolores
    veritatis doloremque fugit. Soluta aperiam atque inventore deleniti,
    voluptatibus non fuga eos magni natus vel, rerum excepturi expedita.
    Tempore, vero!
  </div>
</ScrollSpy>
```

3. Write styles for when the navigation element which is active in your `index.css`

```css
.active-scroll-spy {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Throws an error if you try to use with react 18, just FYI.