# How to add border for li for active link in html on scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

Designing a single page application in reactjs.I have a fixed navbar on the top of the page and i have 4 section .on click of link in navabr it jumps to that particular section.But i want to highlight that li with small border below.if user scrolls to any section without clicking link in navbar,the link must be highlighted with border.

```
// header.js

  <ul className="col-2 flex-row flex-justify-align-center ">
   <li className="navigation__link"><a  href="#problem">Problem</a></li>
   <li className="navigation__link"><a  href="#solution">Solution</a></li>
   <li className="navigation__link"><a href="#footprint">Footprint</a></li>
   <li className="navigation__link"><a  href="#services">Services</a></li>
   <li className="navigation__link"><a  href="#contact">Contact</a></li>             
  </ul>
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="problem"></div>
      <Header></Header>
      <div id="solution">
        <Solution></Solution>
      </div>
      <div id="footprint">
        <Footprint></Footprint>
      </div>
      <div id="contact">
        <Contactus></Contactus>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Question is unclear because I didn't get how to frame question for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use scroll spy. Visit this git repository [React-scrollspy](https://github.com/makotot/react-scrollspy).

relavent question: [How to implement a scrollspy with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966691/how-to-implement-a-scrollspy-with-react)

Comment: @Krazy I am not the person who down voted your question.